# How to parse xml file to array in JavaScript node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, node.js

I'm beginner and I have problem with parse data from xml file to array in Node.js?

Data from xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <record>
       <Name>Apple</Name>
       <Code>AP</Code>
       <Price>2,5</Price>
    </record>
    <record>
       <Name>Kiwi</Name>
       <Code>KI</Code>
       <Price>1,5</Price>
    </record>
</xml>
```

And i expect array like this:

```
var array = [
    { Name: 'Apple', Code: 'AP', Price: '2,5'},
    { Name: 'Kiwi', Code: 'KI', Price: '1,5'}
];
```

---

@EDIT - we're closer

I was trying to use [xml2js npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js), result was:

```
 {                                                            
  "xml": {                                                   
    "$": {                                                   
      "xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    },                                                       
    "record": [                                              
      {                                                      
        "Name": [                                            
          "Apple"                                            
        ],                                                   
        "Code": [                                            
          "AP"                                               
        ],                                                   
        "Price": [                                           
          "2,5"                                              
        ]                                                    
      },                                                     
      {                                                      
        "Name": [                                            
          "Kiwi"                                             
        ],                                                   
        "Code": [                                            
          "KI"                                               
        ],                                                   
        "Price": [                                           
          "1,5"                                              
        ]                                                    
      }                                                      
    ]                                                        
  }                                                          
}
```

My current code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

fs.readFile('test_data.xml', function(err, data){
    parseString(data, function (err, result)
    {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out one of the many XML Parser Packages on npm.

For example: [xml2js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js)

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

If you need help reading the xml File in, check out the nodeJs File System Libary.

[Doc for reading a file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback):

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('/etc/data.xml', (err, data) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

EDIT:
To make it all in one function:

```
function loadXML(cb) {
  fs.readFile('test_data.xml', function(err, data){
    parseString(data, function (err, result) {
      cb(result.xml.record)
    });
  });
}

loadXML(function(yourRecods) {
  // do whatever
});
```

Comment: @DiPix can you post what `JSON.stringify(result, null, 2);` returns?

Comment: just use `var records = result.xml.record;` and you get the array

Comment: Thank you :) should be enough

Comment: One more thing, how can i assign this function to some variable? 
I tried: `var xmlData = fs.readFile('data-xml/test_data.xml', function (err, data)
        {
            parseString(data, function (err, result)
            {
                return result.xml.record;
            });
        });` but it's undefinded when i'll trying to use :/

Comment: Check my edit, you need a function with a callback as parameter

Comment: Ok it works (so complicated for me yet). Anyway i just wondering why `yourRecods[i].name` is **{Array}** instead eg. **Apple**.
I know that i could handle with it by: `yourRecods[i].name[0]`, however is it correct soulution?